# how to use detect finger swipes on screen on outside of app

Tags: android

In my app I want to use `GestureEvents`to detect swipe done by the user like this:

```
GestureDetector gd=new GestureDetector(this,this); //code is implemented in MainActivity of my app

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    return gd.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

    float sensitivity =50;
    if(e1.getX()-e2.getX()>sensitivity){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"left swipe",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    else if(e2.getX()-e1.getX()>sensitivity){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"right swipe",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
   else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

From the above code I can get to know weather user has swiped left or right on screen.But it detects until my activity is in foreground when my app goes background it doesn't detects any motions done on the screen.I want it to work outside of my app too even if the app is destroyed.Is it possible how can I do that please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use below code for swipe detection, may be it is helpful to you, in my project working perfectly, so you can try this..

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;
int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 200;
int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 200;

public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context context) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new CustomGestureListenerClass());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private final class CustomGestureListenerClass extends SimpleOnGestureListener {


    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        singleClicked(e);
        return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent startMotionEvent, MotionEvent endMotionEvent, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        return super.onScroll(startMotionEvent, endMotionEvent, distanceX, distanceY);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent startMotionEvent, MotionEvent endMotionEvent, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = endMotionEvent.getY() - startMotionEvent.getY();
            float diffX = endMotionEvent.getX() - startMotionEvent.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
                result = true;
            }
            result = true;
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
    // if you want done some portion before call this method then write here
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
    // if you want done some portion before call this method then write here
}

public void singleClicked(MotionEvent e) {
}
}
```

**and configure on activity using below code**

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this) {
});
```

Comment: Ok I will try it:)

Comment: hi,it is giving me Runtime exceptions that RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.adarsh.test/com.example.adarsh.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Comment: It is a problem of your Intent.

Please add your Activity in your AndroidManifest.xml.

When you want to make a new activity, you should register it in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Your class OnSwipeTouchListener does not extend any activity nor service how can i register it with manifest please tell me

Comment: @Yogesh_Rathi   Your class OnSwipeTouchListener does not extend any activity nor service how can i register it with manifest please tell me

Comment: @Yogesh_Rathi OK thanks a lot one more question does the above code detects swipes done on outside of my app

Comment: i dont know dear..i dont want reputation i am share only useful code for you....try you will get success best luck

Comment: @Yogesh_Rathi  bro your code works perfectly but doesnt work outside the activity or my app anyway thanks:)

Comment: you can configure in service, check how can pass homescreen view context, then your requirement is full fill

Comment: OK I will try this

Comment: @Yogesh_Rathi hi I have used your code with WindowManager and now according to my requirements it is working great:) thanks for ur time and help